# Prove that a Lebesggue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is an outer measure which assigns to each $d$-dimensional interval its volume.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

I just started to self-study some measure theory. I need to prove the following proposition

> **Proposition**$\quad$ *Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is an outer measure, and it assigns to each $d$-dimensional interval its volume.*

where

> **Definition**$\quad$ Let $X$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the collection of all subsets of $X$. An *outer measure* on $X$ is a function $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,+\infty]$ such that
>
> 1. $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$,
> 2. if $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, then $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(B)$, and
> 3. if $\{A_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of subsets of $X$, then $\mu^*(\bigcup_nA_n)\leq\sum_n\mu^*(A_n)$.

and

> **Definition**$\quad$ We define *Lebesgue outer measure* on $\mathbb{R}^d$ as follows. A *$d$-dimensional interval* is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ of the form $I_1 \times \dots \times I_d$, where $I_1, \dots, I_d$ are subintervals of $\mathbb{R}$ and $I_1 \times \dots \times I_d$ is given by
> \begin{align*}
>     I_1 \times \dots \times I_d = \{(x_1,\dots,x_d):x_i \in I_i\ \text{for } i=1,\dots,d\}.
> \end{align*}
> Note that the intervals $I_1, \dots, I_d$, and hence the $d$-dimensional interval $I_1 \times \dots \times I_d$, can be open, closed, or neither open nor closed. The *volume* of the $d$-dimensional interval $I_1 \times \dots \times I_d$ is the product of the lengths of the intervals $I_1, \dots, I_d$, and will be denoted by $\text{vol}(I_1 \times \dots \times I_d)$. For each subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ let $\mathcal{C}(A)$ be the set of all sequences $\{R_i\}$ of bounded and open $d$-dimensional intervals for which $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_i$. Then $\lambda^*(A)$, the Lebesgue outer measure of $A$ is the infimum of the set
> \begin{align*}
>     \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\text{vol}(R_i):\{R_i\}\in\mathcal{C}(A)\right\}.
> \end{align*}

Here is my attempt:

> **Proof**$\quad$  We begin by verifying that $\lambda^*$ is an outer measure. The relation $\lambda^*(\emptyset)=0$ holds, since for each positive number $\epsilon$ there is a sequence $\{R_i\}$ of bounded and open $d$-dimensional intervals (whose union necessarily includes $\emptyset$) such that $\sum_i\text{vol}(R_i)<\epsilon$; for example, let $R_i = (a_1^i,b_1^i)\times\dots\times(a_d^i,b_d^i)$ where $b_1^i-a_1^i = \dots = b_d^i-a_d^i = \left(\frac{\epsilon}{3 \cdot 2^{i-1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}$, so that $\text{vol}(R_i) = \frac{\epsilon}{3 \cdot 2^{i-1}}$, which implies that $\sum_i\text{vol}(R_i) = \frac{2\epsilon}{3} < \epsilon$.
>
> For the monotonicity of $\lambda^*$, note that if $A \subseteq B$, then each sequence of bounded open $d$-dimensional intervals that covers $B$ also covers $A$, and so $\lambda^*(A) \leq \lambda^*(B)$.
>
> Now consider that countable subadditivity of $\lambda^*$. Let $\{A_b\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an arbitrary sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. If $\sum_n\lambda^*(A_n) = +\infty$, then $\lambda^*(\bigcup_nA_n) \leq \sum_n\lambda^*(A_n)$ certainly holds. So suppose that $\sum_n\lambda^*(A_n) < +\infty$, and let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number. For each $n$ choose a sequence $\{R_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of bounded open $d$-dimensional intervals that covers $A_n$ and satisfies
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\text{vol}(R_{n,i}) < \lambda^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.
> \end{align*}
> If we combine these sequences into one sequence $\{R_j\}$, then the combined sequence satisfies
> \begin{align*}
> \bigcup_nA_n \subseteq \bigcup_jR_j
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_j\text{vol}(R_j) < \sum_n\left(\lambda^*(A_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\right) = \sum_n\lambda^*(A_n) + \epsilon.
> \end{align*}
> These relations, together with the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, imply that $\lambda^*(\bigcup_nA_n) \leq \sum_n\lambda^*(A_n)$. Thus, $\lambda^*$ is an outer measure.
>
> Now we compute the outer measure of the $d$-dimensional intervals of $\mathbb{R}^d$. First consider a closed bounded, and thus compact, $d$-dimensional interval $K$. We cover $K$ with a sequence $\{R_i\}$ of bounded open $d$-dimensional intervals in which the first $d$-dimensional interval is barely larger than $K$, and the sum of the volumes of the other $d$-dimensional intervals is very small; for example, let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number and let $K \subseteq \bigcup_iR_i$ where $\text{vol}(R_1)=\text{vol}(K)+\epsilon$ and $\text{vol}(R_i)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i-1}}$ for $i>1$. Then, $\lambda^*(K) < \text{vol}(K)+2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and so $\lambda^*(K) \leq \text{vol}(K)$. We turn to the reverse inequality. Note that if $K$ is a compact $d$-dimensional interval and if $\{R_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of bounded and open $d$-dimensional for which $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_i$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nR_i$, and $K$ can be decomposed into a finite collection $\{K_j\}_{j=1}^m$ that overlap only on their boundaries and are such that for each $j$ the interior of $K_j$ is included in some $R_i$ (where $i \leq n$). From this it follows that
> \begin{align*}
> \text{vol}(K) = \sum_{j=1}^m\text{vol}(K_j) \leq \sum_i\text{vol}(R_i)
> \end{align*}
> and hence that $\text{vol}(K) \leq \lambda^*(K)$. Therefore, $\text{vol}(K) = \lambda^*(K)$.
>
> The outer measure of an arbitrary bounded $d$-dimensional interval is its volume, since such a $d$-dimensional interval includes and is included in closed bounded intervals of volume arbitrarily close to the volume of itself. Finally, an unbounded $d$-dimensional interval has infinite outer measure, since it includes arbitrarily larger closed bounded $d$-dimensional intervals.

Could someone please help me check if my proof is correct and rigorous? Thanks a lot in advance!

---

To be more specific, I am not confident about the following parts of my proof:

1. When I prove $\lambda^*(\emptyset) = 0$, I constructed a sequences of bounded open $d$-dimensional intervals such that the series is less than $\epsilon$. However, I am not sure whether my construction is appropriate.
2. When proving the countable subadditivity under the assumption of $\sum_n\lambda^*(A_n)<+\infty$, without specifying what exactly the sequence $\{R_{n,i}\}$ is, I only expressed that I want $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\text{vol}(R_{n,i}) < \lambda^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ to be true. Is it rigorous enough to simply put it there? If not, how should I construct a sequence $\{R_i\}$ with its exact elements specified such that the inequality holds?
3. Similarly, when computing the outer measure of a compact $d$-dimensional interval, I failed to specify what exactly the covering sequence of bounded open $d$-dimensional intervals is; instead, I simply expressed that I want $\text{vol}(R_1)=\text{vol}(K)+\epsilon$ and $\text{vol}(R_i)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i-1}}$ for $i>1$ to hold. Is this correct and rigorous? If not, how should I improve it?
4. Finally, if it is necessary, how should one rigorously show that "
   $K$ can be decomposed into a finite collection $\{K_j\}_{j=1}^m$ that overlap only on their boundaries and are such that for each $j$ the interior of $K_j$ is included in some $R_i$ (where $i \leq n$)."

Comment: From the tag description of _solution-verification_: 'For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' Please be more specific.

Comment: @BenSteffan Thanks for you comment! I am amending it.